# Access WP_REST_Server from within plugin namespace

Tags: plugins, rest-api, namespace

I am new to OOP and developing plugins. I have developed a plugin using the Plugin-Boilerplate with namespace. I expanded the boilerplate to include a REST folder and class so I could create custom routs/endpoints. It is working; however I cannot use the WP_REST_Server object. I get the following error: ..class-wp-rest-server.php does not exist.From my limited knowledge of oop my guess I it is not in my namespace. But how do I include/access it? My guess is there is a simple mechanism that is obvious to experienced OOPs. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if this is precisely the problem you're having, but generally if you're in a namespace and want to access something in the global namespace you prefix it with a backslash. i.e. throw new \Exception( ...

Comment: I though I had tried that with no effect. Tried it again and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress (version 5.0) doesn't use namespaces for it's classes, so try to use the global one:

```
\WP_REST_Server
```

to avoid assuming it's in your custom namespace.

One of the reason for this is that WordPress [supports](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) PHP 5.2.4+ that doesn't support namespaces. The minimum is PHP 5.3.3+, if I remember correctly, to support it.

Later this year (2019) WordPress [plans](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/12/08/updating-the-minimum-php-version/) to bump the minimum required PHP version to 5.6 and then to 7 at the end of the year. So after that, WordPress namespaces could be possible, but I'm not aware of any such planned changes though :-)